# What is the name of the technique to allow changing URL formats in PHP?

Tags: php, url, routes

I'm building a webservice that get's a hash, currently:

```
http://example.com/?hash=123abc
```

I want to change it to this format:

```
http://example.com/123abc
```

What is the name of this technique?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called URL Rewriting. You can read about it [here](http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/) and [here](http://www.wisdombay.com/articles/basic%20guide%20to%20mod_rewrite.htm).

Comment: thank you for the links and the straightforward answer!

Answer (score 1):

Create new .htaccess file and content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(A-Za-z0-9-)?$ index.php?hash=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```